# Python. Помогите найти ошибку

Tags: python, циклы

```
print ("введите натуральное число")    
n = input()    
f=0    
print("Введите цифру которую хотите убрать" )    
m= input()    
f=n.replace(m, '')    
m=int    
while(m>=0):    
  if (f!=n):    
     print(f)    
  else:    
     m=input()
```

Нужно чтобы при вводе цифры, которой нет в числе, ввод цифры повторялся.

Comment: Ошибка, впрочем, не единственная, здесь - ``m=int``. Наверняка ни один человек, который написал такое в своем коде, не знает, что делает эта строчка. Думаю, что тебе нужно взять учебник и начать учить язык системно, а не обрывками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вам правильно заметили в комментарии, ошибка была в строке `m=int`. Функция `int` позволяет преобразовать число или строку с числом в тип int (т.е. целое число). Чтобы вызвать функцию, послее неё нужно написать скобки (), чего вы не сделали, поэтому и возникает ошибка при исполнении кода. Кроме того, в скобки нужно указать аргумент, т.е. значение, которое вы хотите привести к типу целого числа. Правильно было бы `m = int(m)`. Но у вас также ошибка в логике построении кода.

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, думаю, такой код вам подойдёт:

```
print("Введите натуральное число:")
n = input()
print("Введите цифру, которую хотите убрать:")
m = input()
while m not in n:  # до тех пор пока m нет в n:
    print("Введенная цифра отсутствует в числе, введите другую:")
    m = input()
# как только условие m not in n перестает выполняться, цикл while
# прекращается и выполняется код ниже:
f = n.replace(m, '')
print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в строке 7:

```py
print ("введите натуральное число")    
n = input()    
f=0    
print("Введите цифру которую хотите убрать" )    
m= input()    
f=n.replace(m, '')    
m=int
```

В строке выше вы присваиваете значение m = int
`int` - по умолчанию встроенный в Python **тип**.
После этого вы сравниваете его:
`(m >= 0)` - то есть, если m - это тип, а 0 -
это число, значит исходный код будет выглядеть так:
`(тип >= число)`
В этом и дело. Python не может обработать это
утверждение, поэтому и выдаёт ошибку.

Вот исправленный код:

```py
print("Введите натуральное число")    
n = int(input())
f = 0
print("Введите цифру, которую хотите убрать")
m = int(input())
f = str(n).replace(str(m), '')
while(m >= 0):
  if (f != n):
     print('Результат: ' + f)
     break
  else:
     m = int(input())
```

Надеюсь, что он работает хорошо.